# Clicking a TD cell in a table and inserting a <select> box element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While my code below seems to work aimlessly to insert a `<select>` element in a `<td>` cell (who's classname is "ufield") when first clicked, the problem now is that, when I go to click on and make a selection in the select box, a new select element gets inserted beside it.

How can I prevent multiple select boxes from being added if there is already one present?

My second question, is that once a selection is made in the target select box, how can I remove the select box and retain its option text value in the target TD cell?

Below is a pic of the problem:

[image]

The desired result is:

[image]
[image]

The Code in question:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(".ufield").click(function() {
    $(this).append("<select><option value='TEST'>TEST</option>");
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td>User ID:</td>
    <td>JSMITH</td>
    <td class="ufield" id="access">TEST</td>
    <td>Floor:</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Account Status:</td>
    <td>active</td>
    <td>Office:</td>
    <td>D5656</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Login:</td>
    <td>30/08/2016 4:16 PM</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Firstname:</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td>175 Yahoo Lane</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lastname:</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Province:</td>
    <td>Ontario</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telephone:</td>
    <td>123-456-7891</td>
    <td>City:</td>
    <td>Niagra Falls</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fax:</td>
    <td>613-990-1301</td>
    <td>Country:</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-mail:</td>
    <td>john_smith@yahoo.ca</td>
    <td>Postal Code:</td>
    <td>90210</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add an if statement to check the children for a `select` element

```
$(document).on('click', '.ufield', function() {
  if($(this).find('select').length == 0) {
      $(this).empty();  //clears out current text in the table
      $(this).append("<select><option value='TEST'>TEST</option>");
  }
});
```

For the second part of your question, you can add an event when the user focuses out of the `select` element.

```
$(document).on('focusout', '.ufield select', function(){
    var myValue = $(this).val();
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $(this).remove();
    $parent.append(myValue);
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.ufield', function() {
  if($(this).find('select').length == 0) {
    $(this).empty(); //clears out the current value in the table cell
    $(this).append("<select><option value='TEST'>TEST</option>");
  }
});

$(document).on('focusout', '.ufield select', function(){
    var myValue = $(this).val();  //gets the current value of the select box
    var $parent = $(this).parent();   //saves the parent element to append the value to later
    $(this).remove();  //removes the select element
    $parent.append(myValue);  //appends the value to the table cell
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td>User ID:</td>
    <td>JSMITH</td>
    <td class="ufield" id="access">TEST</td>
    <td>Floor:</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Account Status:</td>
    <td>active</td>
    <td>Office:</td>
    <td>D5656</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Login:</td>
    <td>30/08/2016 4:16 PM</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Firstname:</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td>175 Yahoo Lane</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lastname:</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Province:</td>
    <td>Ontario</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Telephone:</td>
    <td>123-456-7891</td>
    <td>City:</td>
    <td>Niagra Falls</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fax:</td>
    <td>613-990-1301</td>
    <td>Country:</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-mail:</td>
    <td>john_smith@yahoo.ca</td>
    <td>Postal Code:</td>
    <td>90210</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a class to your field once it's been clicked for the first time. Then, you could add the dropdown to the field only if it *does not have this class*.

```
$(".ufield").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hasSelect') {
      $(this).addClass('hasSelect');
      $(this).append("<select><option value='TEST'>TEST</option>");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must tell to your element to stop listening click events. You can do it with unbind(http://api.jquery.com/unbind/). Your JS code will be something like:

```
 $(".ufield").click(function() {

    $(this).append("<select><option value='TEST'>TEST</option>");
    $(this).unbind('click');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

we need a function to make a new `<select>`that has needed event trigger, each time
 here it is

```js
function NewSelectBox() {
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  var values = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo2'];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var new_opt = document.createElement('option');
    new_opt.setAttribute('value', values[i]);
    new_opt.innerHTML = values[i];
    select.appendChild(new_opt);
  }

  //add the event we need
  $(select).on('change',function(){
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).remove();
    $parent.text(value);
  });

  return select;
}
```

for inserting a `<select>` only If there isn't any ...

```js
$('.ufield').on('click',function () {
    $(this).unbind('click'); // this will unbind click event only for this element (not all '.ufield's select.
    $(this).append( NewSelectBox() );//prepared before
});
```

Comment: Your first example works great, but your second part does not remove the select box.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a way to do this without the use of jQuery incase you wanted that option as well - I don't think it's worth the inclusion of an entire library when a few lines of vanilla JS can handle this easily; but you may be required to use jQuery on your project.

This is two functions; one of them calls on window load and assigns the selection options.

The second option waits for the focus to clear off of the select menu, and populates the secondary table's access TD with the selected value's string. You can do this by "tabbing" away, or clicking somewhere else on the screen such as the next field, ect.

Here's the working example:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input')
var output = document.getElementById('output')


window.onload = addSelections();

function addSelections(){
 var inputString = input.innerHTML = "<select id='selectedInput' ><option value='TEST 1'>TEST 1</option><option value='TEST 2'>TEST 2</option><option value='TEST 3'>TEST 3</option></select>" 
  
var inputListener = document.getElementById("selectedInput");
inputListener.addEventListener("blur", dumpSelections);
}

  
function dumpSelections() {
var selectedInput = document.getElementById('selectedInput')
var outputString = selectedInput.options[selectedInput.selectedIndex].text;
output.innerHTML = outputString;


}
```

```html
<h2>Input Table</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Access</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td id="input" >TEST</td>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Output Table</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Access</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td id="output" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```